# "modules" in kernel module makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel

Consider the following kernel make-file:

```
obj-m += procsview.o
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

default: 
          $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
```

What does mean `modules` in the `default`'s recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`modules` is the target in `$(KDIR)/Makefile` which is executed by `make` (assuming, of course, that `$(MAKE)` refers to a Make executable).